How to solve this Poisson's equation easily?
Here is the system of equations :
\begin{cases}
\Delta u=x^2y,&x^2+y^2 < a^2;\\
u=0,&x^2+y^2=a^2
\end{cases}
I tried to let $v=u-\frac{x^4y}{12}$ , and I get
\begin{cases}
\Delta v = \Delta u -x^2y=0,&x^2+y^2=a^2;\\
v=-\frac{x^4y}{12},&x^2+y^2=a^2
\end{cases}
By Poisson formula I have
\begin{equation}
u(\rho_0,\theta_0)=-\frac{R^5(R^2-\rho_0^2)}{24*2^5\pi}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z^2+1)^4(z^2-1)dz}{z^5(R^2z-R\rho_0((z^2+1)\cos\theta_0-(z^2-1)i \sin\theta_0)+\rho_0^2z)}
\end{equation}
Using Residue theorem I have
\begin{equation}
u(\rho_0,\theta_0)=-\frac{R^5(R^2-\rho_0^2)}{24*2^5\pi}\lim_{z \to 0}\{\frac{(z^2+1)^4(z^2-1)}{R^2z-R\rho_0((z^2+1)\cos\theta_0-(z^2-1)i \sin\theta_0)+\rho_0^2z}\}^{(4)}
\end{equation}
Here $\{\}^{(4)}$ means the fourth derivative of the function.
I think it is too hard to calculate, but the answer is easy. That is $\frac{x^2y(x^2+y^2-a^2)}{18}$ , so I think there may be easier ways to calculate.
How to try it more easily ?

The easiest way to find a solution is to guess it. If you have a candidate for the answer, just check that it satisfies the equation and the boundary condition.

What are the boundary conditions? $u(a,\theta)=0$ and that's it? Or maybe $u(r,0)=u(r,2\pi)$ is one too due to the symmetry of the domain?

According to theory (see Chapter 5 in the freely available textbook Harmonic Function Theory by Axler, Bourdon & Ramey) the Poisson integral of the polynomial $- \tfrac{1}{12} x^4 y$ is itself a polynomial, of the form
$$
v(x,y) = - \tfrac{1}{12} x^4 y + (a^2 - x^2 -y^2) \, q(x,y)
$$
where $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most 3 (two steps lower than the one given on the boundary). And here it's also quite clear that terms in $q$ of degree two or zero won't give anything useful, so just insert
$$
q(x,y) = A x^3 + B x^2 y + C x y^2 + D y^3 + E x + F y
$$
into the expression for $v$, compute $\Delta v$, and see what $(A,B,C,D,E,F)$ have to be in order to get $\Delta v=0$ (you will get a uniquely solvable linear system for those unknowns). The result is
$$
\begin{split}
u(x,y)
&
= v(x,y) + \tfrac{1}{12} x^4 y
\\ &
= (a^2 - x^2 -y^2) \, q(x,y)
\\ &
= \tfrac{1}{192} (a^2 - x^2 -y^2) (-11 x^2 y + y^3 - 2a^2 y)
.
\end{split}
$$
(The solution for $u$ that you gave at the end of your question is clearly incorrect, since it satisfies $\Delta u = x^2 y + \tfrac19 (y^3 - a^2 y) \ne x^2 y.)$

Let's rewrite the equation in polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}
&=r^3\cos^2\theta \sin\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{2}r^3\cos\theta \sin 2\theta \\
&=\frac{1}{4}r^3(\sin 3\theta+\sin\theta). \tag{1}
\end{align}
Since $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta^2}\sin(n\theta)=-n^2\sin(n\theta)$, the RHS of $(1)$ suggests the ansatz
$$
u(r,\theta)=f_1(r)\sin\theta+f_3(r)\sin 3\theta, \tag{2}
$$
$$
f_1(a)=f_3(a)=0. \tag{3}
$$
Plugging $(2)$ into $(1)$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=1,3}\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{d}{dr}f_n(r)\right)-\frac{n^2}{r^2}f_n(r)\right)\sin(n\theta)=\sum_{n=1,3}
\frac{1}{4}r^3\sin(n\theta)
$$
$$
\implies f_n''(r)+\frac{1}{r}f_n'(r)-\frac{n^2}{r^2}f_n(r)=\frac{1}{4}r^3
\qquad(n=1,3). \tag{4}
$$
Equation $(4)$ is an inhomogeneous Cauchy-Euler equation. One can easily verify that its general solution is
$$
f_n(r)=A_nr^n+B_nr^{-n}+\frac{r^5}{4(25-n^2)}. \tag{5}
$$
Regularity at $r=0$ implies $B_n=0$, and the boundary condition $f_n(a)=0$ implies $A_n=-\frac{a^{5-n}}{4(25-n^2)}$. Therefore, combining $(2)$ and $(5)$ we finally obtain
$$
u(r,\theta)=\left(\frac{r^5-a^4r}{96}\right)\sin\theta
+\left(\frac{r^5-a^2r^3}{64}\right)\sin 3\theta. \tag{6}
$$

I got up until $(5)$ a few days ago and I was really stuck. Thanks for providing a full answer; it cleared all my doubts.
